# onClick firing multiple times JS

Tags: javascript, html

I've created an HTML form with JS validation. I've called the function through a button via onclick but it is firing multiple times resulting in unnecessary blank form data. Here's the code.

I'm pushing the data to firebase realtime db.

I'm new to JS, any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<form class="subscribe-form" id="subscribe-form">
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <input class="email-input" name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
     <button onclick="updateSubscribeEmail();" class="sitebtn btn-submit" 
      type="submit">Subscribe</button></div>
</form>
```

JS

```
function updateSubscribeEmail() {
    // Reference messages collection
    var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref("Subscription Emails");
    var resetForm = document.getElementById("subscribe-form");
    // Listen for form submit
    document.getElementById("subscribe-form").addEventListener("submit", submitSubscribeForm);
    // Submit form

    function submitSubscribeForm(e) {
        // To avoid entire page getting refreshed
        e.preventDefault();

        var email = getInputVal("email");
        // Get values
        var text;
        console.log("Before Validation");
        if (email.indexOf("@") === -1 || email.length < 6) {
            console.log("After Validation");
            text = "Please enter a valid email address!";
            red_inner_html.innerHTML = text;
            red_div.style.display = "block";
            setTimeout(function () {
                red_div.style.display = "none";
            }, 5000);
        } else {
            saveMessage(email);
            console.log("Before reset");
            resetForm.reset();
            console.log("after reset");
            text = "You have successfully subscribed!";
            green_inner_html.innerHTML = text;
            green_div.style.display = "block";
            setTimeout(function () {
                green_div.style.display = "none";
            }, 5000);
        }
    }

    // Function to get get form values
    function getInputVal(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id).value;
    }

    // Save message to firebase
    function saveMessage(email) {
        var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
        newMessageRef.set({
            Email: email
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You're adding an event listener every time you click the button. JS event listeners don't automatically replace each other; they stack. Each time you click the button you tell it to call that listener another time the next time you submit the form. Only add the event listener one time. You can just move that line of code outside of the `updateSubscribeEmail` function to the global scope.

Comment: OMG! It's working as expected. I just moved the event listener out of the function as you said and also removed the nested function (submitSubscribeForm) Thank you so much. I was stuck here since yesterday.